# approaching a limit in 3-d from different lines

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

Given $\lim_{x,y\to 0,0}$ $\frac{xy^4}{x^2+y^8}$ The answer is 0. I have no problem obtaining zero when approaching along the x and y axis however:

approaching along the line x= y^4 I get:
$\lim_{Y^4,y\to 0,0 }\frac{y^4y^4}{y^8+y^8}$ = $\frac{y^8}{2y^8}$ = $\frac{1}{2}$

approaching along the line y=x gives:
$\lim_{x,x\to 0,0} \frac{xx^4}{x^2+x^8}$ = $\frac{x^5}{x^2(1+x^6)}$ = $\frac{x^3}{1+x^6}$

None of these make sense to me as to how they would equate to zero. The only logical explanation I can come up with for the second case is that it yields and indeterminate form because I have variables in the numerator and denominator that would give $\frac{0}{0}$ Is that correct? From the lecture notes I was looking at it, I was under the impression that if you could find an algebraic substitution that would get cancellation as in the first case then it would be easy to show that it does not exist.

Comment: As you've shown, the limit is 0 when you approach the origin along the x-axis and is $\frac{1}{2}$ when you approach the origin along the curve $x=y^4$, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I think wolfram alpha gave me bad answer as it was an even exercise in my book so I used that to check my answer. I'm surprised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second case, the limiting form is $\frac{0}{1+0}$ which is just $0$. There is only a "problem" if you have a form $\frac00$.

Since you have shown that the limit depends on the manner of approach, you have demonstrated that the limit does not exist.

It isn't $0$, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and pointing out my error in the second case. As I had not shown it was 0+1 in the denominator.